# Pull in Earlier Value Using Concatenation

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that works in some situations but not in others.

I have this code:

```
 Public Sub ListBox2_LostFocus() 
ListBox2.Height = 15 
   With ListBox2 
   ThisIs_Sheet1_Test = "'" 
   For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1 
        If .Selected(i) Then 
        ThisIS_Sheet1_Test = ThisIs_Sheet1_Test & .List(i) & "','" 
    End If 
Next i 
End With 
ThisIs_Sheet1_Test = Left(ThisIs_Sheet1_Test, Len(ThisIs_Sheet1_Test) - 2) 
End Sub
```

that produces "ThisIs_Sheet1_Test". So when I run the code below, it gives me the selected values in the listbox.

```
Public Sub dummy() 
Dim SheetName As String 

SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name 

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I5", "I5") = ThisIs_Sheet1_Test

End Sub
```

However, when I use

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I5", "I5") = "ThisIs_" & SheetName & "_Test"
```

I get the value of "ThisIs_SheetName_Test" which is obviously not what I'm looking for.

How to I bring in the value and then have the VBA recognize that it should be pulling in the earlier value?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of this code? There are some improvements that I would suggest, but rather than focus on the detail of your existing code, it might be better to just cut to the chase and suggest a solution to your problem. Is it just that you want a list of the selected values in the listbox to be inserted in a cell on the same worksheet?

Comment: Exactly right. I want the selected values to display in sheet1, cell I5 (I also have other pages with other cells that I would like it to display in, but I figure if I can do it once, I can copy the form). Thanks.

Comment: Have you some objection to passing in the sheet name and/or range and using that to write directly to the sheet?

Comment: Well, in the end I'd like to create a macro so all I'll have to do is have the code once (on each of my 5 pages, plus 10 times on each sheet) and it will automatically pull it all to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ThisIs_Sheet1_Test` as a *variable* to hold a value (even though you don't explicitly declare the variable). You can't just assemble a string with the same name and expect it to somehow know what you want (to get the value held in the variable).

I'm assuming you are trying to do this because each sheet might have different values to track. In that case, here are a few options:

- Explicitly declare a public string array, with enough values for each of your sheets. Then you can track each of your values using the index number of the worksheet you are on.
- Instead of using a variable, pick a hidden spreadsheet cell to hold the value, then you can just use `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Z100").Value` or something similar.  This is a bit "hacky", and also fragile (because the user can overwrite the cell if it isn't locked or hidden), but might work the best without a bunch of other code.
- Use "custom properties" of the worksheet. This would look something like:

  ```
  Dim mySheet As Worksheet
  Set mySheet = ActiveSheet

  'mySheet.CustomProperties.Item(1).Delete
  mySheet.CustomProperties.Add "ListboxValues", "one,two,three"

  MsgBox mySheet.CustomProperties.Item(1).Name & " = " & _
         mySheet.CustomProperties.Item(1).Value
  ```

If you only use a single custom property like my example, they are pretty easy to use. Once you have more than one, then you have to loop through to find the custom property with the correct name, and use that.

Comment: I understand what I have been doing wrong. Is there a way to dim "ThisIs_" & SheetName & "Test" at the top and then not have to worry about it down below?

Not sure what my next step is.

Comment: No, you can't declare a variable with a name assembled from other variables. See my 3 other options mentioned above.

Comment: How about this: If I create names for each page: ex. ThisIs_Sheet1_Test, ThisIs_Sheet2_Test, etc. is there a way to create a macro that passes in different values based on the sheet?

If activesheet=sheet2, then it would pass in ThisIs_Sheet2_Test

?

Comment: I'd like a little more information on the custom property. It looks like the most reasonable. Here's more information from me:

I have 5 sheets and on each sheet are 3 listboxes. Each listbox is populated dynamically with between 3 and 10 values.

So for each sheet, there will be three values, something similar to this:

ThisIs_Sheet1_Test
ThisIs_Sheet1_Testing
ThisIs_Sheet1_Tested

Is this doable using your suggestion? I'm not familiar with it so the more specific you can be the better! Thanks!

Comment: Sure, that's doable. You'll just to need add 3 different custom properties, one for each listbox. Might be a bit of code, though. I still wonder if you might have an easier time just storing the value in a cell on the spreadsheet? (Maybe the cell hidden behind the listbox itself?) Then all you'd have to do is `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B12").Value`

Comment: I see what you're saying, but then on the commandbutton click, I have it throw the data into that hidden cell. That's fine, except that for each sheet, I have to put it there, so I have to take the ThisIs_Sheet1_Test and put it into that cell with code. And then I am back at the same problem of having 3 lines of code for each sheet instead of being able to macro it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using my solution to earlier question verbatim. 
Perhaps if you want to use valu of an variable that you set in in one function in another you need to declare it out side..

So move your Dim SheetName As String to bigining of the module, all the way up to first line.

Comment: It's already there. This was just an example, showing ONLY the relevant code.

Like the answer below said, it looks like a variable/string/text problem. How do I get around that?